# Definition of variables inside constructor causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault, set

I am writing an implementation of a set using a doubly linked list with sentinal _head and _tail nodes. Each node is defined by the Elem struct. I included only the parts of my code that are causing the problem:

**set.h**

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Set {
    public:
        Set();
        ~Set();
    private:
        struct Elem {
            string info;
            Elem *prev, *next;
        };
        Elem *_head, *_tail;
        int _size;
};
```

**set.cpp**

```
#include "set.h"
using namespace std;
Set::Set() {
    _size = 0;  // Segmentation fault from this
    _head = new Elem;
    _tail = new Elem;
    _head = nullptr;    // Segmentation fault from this
    _tail = nullptr;    // Segmentation fault from this
    _head->next = _tail;
    _tail->prev = _head;
}
Set::~Set() {
    while (_head->next != _tail) {
        _head->next = _head->next->next;
        delete _head->next->prev;
    }
}
```

**setTest.cpp**

```
#include "set.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Set s1;
}
```

The above code is causing a segmentation fault when I run the test driver "setTest.cpp". I did a bit of debugging and I isolated the parts that are causing the the error. It seems to be the three lines that are defining the _size, _head, and _tail variables.

Why would the definition of these variables/pointers in the constructor cause a segmentation fault?

Comment: Why are you newing the pointers to just set them to null?

Comment: It's *definitely not* from `_size = 0;`.

Comment: Did you mean to say `_head->next = nullptr`? otherwise why `new` something then immediately leak it?

Comment: You also need `_head->prev = nullptr` and `_tail->next = nullptr`, otherwise they are uninitialized pointers.  Also, the destructor is leaking `_head` and `_tail` as it does not `delete` them, and the way the destructor is looping through nodes is just odd in general. And you are missing a copy constructor and copy assignment operator (see [Rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three))

Comment: `_head = nullptr;  _head->next = _tail;` is an excellent way getting a segmentation fault. You are accessing a member through a pointer you *just* nulled a moment before.

Comment: your `_head` is `nullptr` at the moment you run into `_head->next = _tail;`

Comment: You are all right, the problem is with making _head and _tail null, I was assuming that in order to create dummy sentinel nodes I had to set the whole node to null, what I should have is it's `info` be null instead

Comment: In future, please post the example code all in one piece, not with user-defined .h files and multiple .cpp's.

Comment: In the future, search the internet or StackOverflow before posting.  There already very many posts about linked lists and nodes that you can learn from.

Comment: @Sean: Personally, I wouldn't bother using sentinel nodes at all. When your Set is empty, it makes sense for `_head` and `_tail` to be null initially, since no other nodes exist yet, and then update `_head` and `_tails` as nodes are added/removed later on. But, it is up to you to decide. Sentinel nodes also work, if you manage them correctly. Either way, for future reference, when you find a solution to a problem, DONT edit your question to show the solution.  Accept someone's answer that lead you to the solution, or post your own answer if needed.  This is a Question **and Answer** site

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by setting _head and _tail to null. By setting them to null and then trying to access their prev and next pointers which did not "exist" anymore.